# Call to Firebase happens only once when i open the page , then it never happens when i navigate back to it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Am doing a call to the firebase from my ionic 4 project that gets a list of items. it only happens once I launch the app for the first time, then if I navigate to another page then back to this page. it shows a blank list. here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DressService, Dress } from '../services/dress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {
  dress: Dress[];
  constructor(private dressService: DressService,
  ) {
    this.dressService.getDresses().subscribe(res => {
      this.dress = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  // add back when alpha.4 is out
  // navigate(item) {
  //   this.router.navigate(['/list', JSON.stringify(item)]);
  // }
}
```

And here is how I view the list in my `HTML` page

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of dress" >
            <img src="{{item.image_1}}">
            <ion-label dir="rtl">
                <small>{{item.category}}</small>
                <br>
                <ion-text color="secondary">
                    <b>{{item.title}}</b>
                </ion-text>
                <br>
                <ion-badge color="danger">{{item.price}} EGP</ion-badge>
                <br>
                <small>{{item.city}}</small>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Where's the call to firebase? Is it in your dressService? If so, it's probably just because your subscribing. It should only update when there are changes. Also, does that belong in your constructor? Why not in the ngInit? If it goes in your init, then you'll need to unsubscribe in an NgDestroy.

Comment: @SeanKPS it is in the `dressServices `, and I tried adding it to the `nginit`  still it only loads once. can you explain how to unsubscribe in a NgDestroy ??

Comment: @SeanKPS when I try to use `unsubscribe` i get `Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Dress[]>'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @SeanKPS Comment, I needed to use `unsubscribe` on the `ngOnDestroy`.

Changed my code to be like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DressService, Dress } from '../services/dress.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, ObjectUnsubscribedError } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {
  dress: Dress[];
  mySub: any;
  constructor(private dressService: DressService,
              private router: Router,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mySub = this.dressService.getDresses().subscribe(res => {
      this.dress = res;
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.mySub.unsubscribe();
  }
  // add back when alpha.4 is out
  // navigate(item) {
  //   this.router.navigate(['/list', JSON.stringify(item)]);
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using a router in your app? If so, you could subscribe to a Router instance and do something when the route changes.

```
       constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe(() => shouldGetDresses());
       }

       private shouldGetDresses() {
        this.dressService.getDresses().subscribe(res => {
        this.dress = res;
       });
      }
```